# Where is the segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, portaudio

I know not everyone has used the PortAudio API, but maybe you can find it in here anyway.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "portaudio.h"

int main() {    
    PaDeviceIndex outputDevice;
    PaDeviceIndex deviceCount;
    outputDevice = Pa_GetDefaultOutputDevice();
    deviceCount = Pa_GetDeviceCount();
    const PaDeviceInfo * outputDeviceInfo;
    outputDeviceInfo = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(outputDevice);
    std::cout << "Name of default output device: " << outputDeviceInfo->name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Struct version: " << outputDeviceInfo->structVersion << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT: ** sorry guys, I didn't know there even was a debugger. I wasn't trying to be rude or inconsiderate. It said it's caused by line 12 and 13, the ones that begin with std::cout. I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: You prefer using people as debuggers?

Comment: Well, **you** can tell **us** where the seg-fault is by running this in the debugger, which will tell you which line caused it.

Comment: Is it perchance where you're trying to write to the `outputDeviceInfo` pointer you previously declared `const`?

Comment: on what line is the error? please post the error stack trace

Comment: @rjz: The pointer is not const.

Comment: I know not everyone provides this little detail in their questions, but try to post some more anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null pointer dereference. `Pa_GetDeviceInfo` is returning a null pointer.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x080487f4 in main () at pa.cpp:12
12      std::cout << "Name of default output device: " << outputDeviceInfo->name << std::endl;
(gdb) print outputDeviceInfo
$1 = (const PaDeviceInfo *) 0x0
```

Comment: Oh, I get it. I think it's because for some reason PortAudio isn't recognizing the default output device, so I guess I have to configure it or something. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://audacity.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.3.6-1/lib-src_2portaudio-v19_2include_2portaudio_8h_c7d8e091ffc1d1d4a035704660e117eb.html):

> `const PaDeviceInfo* Pa_GetDeviceInfo     (   PaDeviceIndex   device   )`
>
> Retrieve a pointer to a `PaDeviceInfo` structure containing information about the specified device.
>
> **Returns:**
>       A pointer to an immutable `PaDeviceInfo` structure. If the device parameter is out of range the function returns `NULL`.

You forgot to check for `NULL` before dereferencing the pointer. Oops.